# How to replace strings in a List

Tags: c#, list, csv, replace, datagridview

I got values from a .csv file and put them into a datagridview, but I'd like to replace some values before to fill my datagridview.

This is the screen of my .csv file:

[image]

and this is my code to try to do it:

```
string FileName = @"C:\mydir\testcsv.csv";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
           ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
             Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) +
             "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");

    conn.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
           ("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    conn.Close();

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    List<HT> matchhtList = new List<HT>();
    matchhtList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                   select new HT()
                   {
                       Home = dr["Home"].ToString(),
                       Away = dr["Away"].ToString(),
                       ScoreHome = dr["ScoreHome"].ToString(),
                       ScoreAway = dr["ScoreAway"].ToString(),
                       Segno = dr["Segno"].ToString(),
                       odd1 = dr["odd1"].ToString(),
                       oddx = dr["oddx"].ToString(),
                       odd2 = dr["odd2"].ToString()

                   }).ToList();

    StringBuilder mystring = new StringBuilder("matchhtList");
    mystring = mystring.Replace("Rosenborg", "Rihanna")
           .Replace("Start", "Stop")
           .Replace("Brann", "Circus");

    dataGridView2.DataSource = mystring;
```

**Please, if my question is not clear, tell me before to put "-1", I'll try to explain better my question. Thank you very much!**

Comment: You  likely had the downvote due to "but its not working". What precisely isn;t working? is there an exception etc. This is the detail thats missing.

Comment: As it happens, you're setting your datasource to a string - not your actual data....

Comment: ok, I made a mistake, but please don't give me a downvote, just for this time. I deleted the wrong question...

Comment: I didn;t downvote - not my style :) just giving reasons why you might have been.

Comment: Thank you, I will be careful next time :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace the the text when you build the list

```
matchhtList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                   select new HT()
                   {
                       Home = dr["Home"].ToString().Replace("Rosenborg", "Rihanna"),
                       Away = dr["Away"].ToString().Replace("Start", "Stop").Replace("Brann", "Circus"),
                       ScoreHome = dr["ScoreHome"].ToString(),
                       ScoreAway = dr["ScoreAway"].ToString(),
                       Segno = dr["Segno"].ToString(),
                       odd1 = dr["odd1"].ToString(),
                       oddx = dr["oddx"].ToString(),
                       odd2 = dr["odd2"].ToString()

                   }).ToList();

dataGridView2.DataSource = matchhtList;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the values in `rowdatabound` event of gridview

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

And your `datasource` must be a List or `DataTable` in above scenario.

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = mystring;//Wrong
```

should be

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = matchList;
```